# Getting null pointer exception when jpa query not found a row in database

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to get result of my query from my database with jpa. When the query founds nothing in the database, it returns null pointer exception. I tried to check it if statement like in below code but I still getting null pointer exception.

```
public List<String> getQuestionSavedUser(String salesOrder, String module,int questionID)
    {
        List<String> singleUser= entityManager.createQuery("select i.savedBy from EVMResponses i where i.salesOrder='"+salesOrder+"' AND i.module='"+module+"' AND i.questionID="+questionID+"", String.class).getResultList(); 
        System.out.println(singleUser.size());
        if(singleUser.size()>0&&singleUser.get(0)!=null)
        {
            users.add(singleUser.get(0));
        }
        else
        {
            users.add("");
        }
        return users;
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public List<String> getQuestionSavedUser(String salesOrder, String module,int questionID)
    {
        List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> singleUser= entityManager.createQuery("select i.savedBy from EVMResponses i where i.salesOrder='"+salesOrder+"' AND i.module='"+module+"' AND i.questionID="+questionID+"", String.class).getResultList(); 
        System.out.println(singleUser.size());
        if(singleUser.size()>0&&singleUser.get(0)!=null)
        {
            users.add(singleUser.get(0));
        }
        else
        {
            users.add("");
        }
        return users;
    }
```

Comment: You're right when I forgot to define users, after the defining the problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the **entityManager** is null,check it!
or you can use:

```
List<String> singleUser = new ArrayList<>();
singleUser = entityManager.createQuery("select i.savedBy from EVMResponses i where i.salesOrder='"+salesOrder+"' AND i.module='"+module+"' AND i.questionID="+questionID+"", String.class).getResultList();
```

to see whether entityManager works well  or not. \

Comment: The entityManager works fine and it's not null also I tried with this **List<String> singleUser = new ArrayList<>();** but I'm still getting error on this code **users.add(singleUser.get(0));**

Comment: seems that you never define the users

Comment: i rewrite an answer, it may suit this